# Iterative and recursive approach to generate Fibonacci sequence

Tags: recursion, iteration

I'm new to use Mathematica and using this demo project to understand Mathematic [demo example](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IterationVersusRecursionInTheFibonacciSequence/).
I modified example code to only plot the runtime of recursive version of Fibonacci sequence runtime:

```
Clear[recFib];
recFib[n_] := recFib[n] = recFib[n - 1] + recFib[n - 2]
recFib[0] = 0; recFib[1] = 1;

timeComplex[n_] := 
    Plot[{recFib[x], x}, {x, 0, n}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 100}},
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Thickness[0.01]}, 
    PlotLabel ->  "time complexity", AxesLabel -> {n, time}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"recursive"}, 
       LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
       LegendLayout -> "Column"], {{0.25, 0.5}, {0.25, 0.1}}], 
       ImageSize -> {200, 200}]


    Manipulate[
       GraphicsGrid[{{timeComplex[n]}}, Alignment -> {Center, Top}, 
       Frame -> All], {{n, 2, "Fibonacci number"}, 2, 10, 1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
       SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

However, the output graph still contains iterative runtime of Fibonacci. Could someone teach me where it comes from? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that it only contains a straight line? Try maybe DiscretePlot instead of Plot in your definition of timeComplex. I think Plot would not play well with recFib which is only properly defined for integer values of n.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default when you use `Plot`, it uses very small numbers to give you a smooth plot and in this case, this is not what you want. Because if you use step values less than $1$, like `recFib[3.5]`, the program will fall short in recursion without any result.

Solution is to specify plot step as `1`, since `Plot` doesn't have a step option, you can use `DiscretePlot` as shown below ( $...$ is the options you have specified):

```
timeComplex[n_] :=  DiscretePlot[{recFib[x], x}, {x, 0, n, 1}, Joined -> True, Filling -> None, ...]
```

[image]

Also for the `AxesLabel` you use symbols, not strings, so I change `time` to `"time"` and `n` to `"n"`.

Full code:

```
recFib[n_] := recFib[n] = recFib[n - 1] + recFib[n - 2]
recFib[0] = 0; recFib[1] = 1;

timeComplex[n_] := 
 DiscretePlot[{recFib[x], x}, {x, 0, n, 1}, Joined -> True, 
  Filling -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 100}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Thickness[0.01]}, 
  PlotLabel -> "time complexity", AxesLabel -> {"n", "time"}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"recursive"}, LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
     LegendLayout -> "Column"], {{0.25, 0.5}, {0.25, 0.1}}], 
  ImageSize -> {200, 200}]

Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[{{timeComplex[n]}}, Alignment -> {Center, Top}, 
  Frame -> All], {{n, 2, "Fibonacci number"}, 2, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you very much!